# Opposite of a complicated query?

Tags: mysql

[Query Image - Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txayo.png)

```
Select
random.verbvocabconnector.id,
random.verbvocabconnector.verbid,
random.verbvocabconnector.vocabid,
random.verbs.id As id1,
random.verbs.verb,
random.vocabulary.id As id2,
random.vocabulary.vocabulary
From
random.verbvocabconnector Inner Join
random.vocabulary
On random.vocabulary.id = random.verbvocabconnector.vocabid Inner Join
random.verbs
On random.verbvocabconnector.verbid = random.verbs.id
Where
random.vocabulary.id = 2
```

By using the variable **vocabid** I can list all the verbs that is connected with the vocabulary. But I want to do the opposite, if the id is 2 then dont show the verbs that is connected to that vocabulary and show all the others. You can see the detailed table structure on the image. Thanks in advance.

Edit : I got these tables : verbs, vocabulary, verbandvocabconnector.

```
CREATE TABLE `verbs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `verb` text NOT NULL,
  `regularorirregular` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `irregular` text NOT NULL,
  `irregular2` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `verbs` (`id`, `verb`, `regularorirregular`, `irregular`, `irregular2`) 
VALUES
(1, 'eat', 1, 'ate', 'eaten'),
(2, 'repair', 0, '', ''),
(3, 'clean', 0, '', ''),
(4, 'use', 1, 'used', 'used'),
(8, 'slice', 1, 'sliced', 'sliced'),
(6, 'drink', 1, 'drank', 'drunk'),
(7, 'wash', 0, '', '');

CREATE TABLE `vocabulary` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vocabulary` text NOT NULL,
  `category` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `vocabulary` (`id`, `vocabulary`, `category`) 
VALUES
(1, 'apple', 'fruits'),
(2, 'your car', 'object'),
(3, 'his toothbrush', 'object'),
(4, 'banana', 'fruits'),
(5, 'our dishwasher', 'object'),
(6, 'tea', 'drinks'),
(7, 'soda', 'drinks'),
(8, 'fruit juice', 'drinks');

CREATE TABLE `verbvocabconnector` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `verbid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vocabid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `verbvocabconnector` (`id`, `verbid`, `vocabid`) 
VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 4),
(3, 2, 2),
(4, 2, 5),
(6, 3, 2),
(7, 3, 3),
(8, 3, 5),
(9, 4, 2),
(10, 4, 3),
(11, 4, 5),
(13, 5, 2),
(14, 5, 5),
(15, 6, 6),
(16, 6, 7),
(17, 6, 8),
(18, 7, 2),
(19, 7, 1),
(20, 7, 3),
(21, 8, 1),
(22, 8, 4);
```

And the output I want to get from these tables ; When I select the vocabulary where id = 2, it should list that the verbs that are not connected in the connector table. If the second vocab is "your car" it should not list **"repair, clean, use, wash"** and must list **"eat, slice, drink."**

Comment: You mean like what you get when you use `WHERE random.vocabulary.id <> 2`?

Comment: That would be a 'simple' query

Comment: I already did that but no luck as it sems. It lists every verb two or three times according to their count on the connector table. Thanks. @KenWhite

Comment: @Strawberry Do you mind explaining if there is a better way to handle the solution ?

Comment: Put sample data (as text, not an image) and the output you'd like to obtain from that data. Your question is pretty unclear, and you can't run test queries against data in an image.

Comment: I tried to do add some more information about the problem. I hope it helps. Thanks. @KenWhite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problems like this, I start with what I'm looking for which is verbs.

```
select * from verbs where ...
```

You mentioned that you can build a query to find the verbs that are associated with vocabulary 2 by joining the tables.

```
select verbid from verbvocabconnector 
where verbvocabconnector.VOCABID = 2
```

Combining these two, you need the verbs that are not returned by this query.  As long as you are only returning the verb ids, you can select verbs that have ids in, or for this case, not in that subquery selection

```
select * from verbs
where id not in (subquery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also liked your answering style, not giving the exact solution to a problem but giving hints really improves learners like me. Can't thank enough. I learnt something new thanks to you. I hope the good things will be on your side as long as you breathe.